# Retornar na tela uma informação do banco de dados com Python

Tags: mysql, python

tenho o seguinte código:

```
# Lista dos produtos

produtos = {'1':('Dipirona 500mg 10 cp', 2.99),
            '2':('Paracetamol 500mg 10 cp', 4.7),
            '3':('Ibuprofeno 600 mg 4 cp ', 5.98),
            '4':('Dorflex 10 cp', 10.99),
            '5':('Neosoro', 3.49),
            '6':('Torsilax 4 cp', 5.99)}

total_compra = valor_item = troco = 0 # variável para total da compra, valor unitário do item e para o troco
produtos_comprados = [] # lista que receberá os itens 'escaneados'/digitados
qtd_produtos = 0 # variável que recebe a quantidade de produtos


while True:
  codigo = str(input('\nDigite o código de um produto: '))
  if len(codigo) > 0:
    if codigo in produtos.keys():
      print(f'Produto.: {produtos.get(codigo)[0]}')
      descricao_produto = produtos.get(codigo)[0]
      print(f'Valor...: R$ {produtos.get(codigo)[1]:.2f}')
      valor_pro = produtos.get(codigo)[1]
      qtd_produtos += 1
      total_compra += valor_pro
      produtos_comprados.append([codigo, valor_pro, descricao_produto])
    else:
      print('Código de produto inválido')
  else:
    break
```

---

Está funcionando normalmente, só que agora eu quero esse mesmo código faça consulta no banco de dados MYSQL (ao invés de consultar o dicionário) . Já criei a tabela e o database no MYSQL, já instalei o MYSQL conector via pip, já fiz a importação e a conexão com o banco. Só queria mesmo saber como escrever a sintaxe de como ele busca no banco e retorna o nome do produto e o preço. Depois, preciso que ele acrescente os itens buscados em uma lista local, porque os itens comprados serão mostrados na nota fiscal na tela.

No tabela eu tenho os mesmos campos: código(integer) , produto(varchar) e preço(float).Ao digitar o código , preciso que ele me retorne na tela o produto e o preço. Grato pela atenção e pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos aos passos

### Instale a biblioteca

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

### Conectando ao banco

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="db_host",
  user="usuario",
  password="senha"
)

cursor = mydb.cursor()
```

## Acessando os dados

```
codigo = input('\nDigite o código de um produto: ')   # Nao precisa do str()
sql = f"select produto, preco from produtos where codigo = '{codigo}';"

cursor.execute(sql)

for (produto, preco) in cursor:
    print(produto, preco)
```

**Atualização** havia esquecido o `from produtos` (*from table*)

**Nota** Dê uma olhada em [fetchall()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html) e [fetchone()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html)

### Fechando conexão com banco

```
cursor.close()
mydb.close()
```

Comment: Respondido no post

Comment: Oi Paulo Marques, tudo bem? 

Não entendi essa string formatada 

sql = f"select produto, preco where codigo = '{codigo}';" . Como ele vai fazer select dentro um format string? ele vai retornar o texto literal não? 

De qualquer forma, está dando o seguinte erro:

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'produto' in 'field list'

Comment: O código no git (sem conexão com o banco da dados) se quiser conferir

https://gist.github.com/jonathasfrsantos/ae00deb04e53f1794017a128707bd728

Comment: Opa, eu havia esquecido o _from tabela_ na query. Atualizei o post. A query é executada na linha `cursor.execute(sql)` vc pode colocar a string direto lá.

Comment: Funcionou amigo! Agora eu preciso que ele inclua os itens buscados em uma lista chamada "produtos_comprados". Não faço ideia como criar as variáveis onde ele receba "nome_produto" e "preço" e depois pegue esses valores e insira numa lista.

Comment: Melhor abrir outro post com esta questão.